# How to prepare queries in PHP MVC facade pattern?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, database-connection, prepared-statement, facade

How to prevent an app against SQL injection using prepared statements for each SQL query.

I have some "manager" classes that handle queries and call static methods from a specific class designed for database connexion and query running. This one creates a connexion for each query and has some generic public static methods getAll(), getOne(), exec() to treat all kinds of queries.

Where can I do the db->prepare, BindParam, and execute statements ? Manager class side, no connexion initialized, so db->prepare is impossible.
Database class side, the method are generic so parameters are variable depending on the method calling the static method.

To have a clearer idea of what I'm trying to explain here, you can see my code here : https://github.com/code-climber/car_rental/tree/master/src/car_rental/model/dao

You can check the way I write my SQL queries in CarManager.class.php and the way they are treated in DBOperation.class.php.

I hope this problem will clear important concepts in my mind in OOP PHP programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Query in one parameter, then pass the values in a second parameter. So for example in your DBOperation Class change the `function getAll($sQuery)` to `function ($sQuery,$sQData){}.`

where `$sQData` is an array containing all the values your going to bind into your query. Then just bind your Query and Parameters and execute your function.

So you could define `$sQData` like :

```
array("key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2","key3"=>"value3");
```

Then iterate through your array like :

```
foreach($sQData as $key=>$value){}
```

Comment: Ok, this is close to work, just one thing I don't get. When I loop through the query parameters array, I write $stmt->bindParam($key, $value), but what is stored in the database table is the key. For example I get :login in my table instead of getting what my true login is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally solved the problem by mixing different answers.

The query and the way it is passed to the class in charge of execution look like this. Beginners like me, do not put quotes around `VALUES` parameters :

```
$sQuery = 'INSERT INTO Clients (first_name, last_name, email, login, passwd) ';
$sQuery .= "VALUES (:firstName,:lastName,:email,:login,:saltedPasswd)";
$aQueryParams = array(':firstName' => $sFirstName,':lastName' => $sLastName,':email' => $sEmail,':login' => $sLogin,':saltedPasswd'=>$sPasswordSalted);
$bSuccess = DBOperation::exec($sQuery,$aQueryParams);
```

And now the content of the `exec()` method in the `DBOperation` class.

```
public static function exec($sQuery,$aQueryParams){
        self::init();
        try {
            $stmt = self::$oDataBase->prepare($sQuery);
            $iAffectedRows = $stmt->execute($aQueryParams) or die(print_r(self::$oDataBase->errorInfo()));
        } catch (PDOException $oPdoException) {
            echo 'PDO Exception : ' . $oPdoException->getMessage();
        }
        return false !== $iAffectedRows;
    }
```

I do not use the `foreach()` loop because I read that I can use the array of parameters directly in `execute()` and if I was supposed to deal with, I should use a reference for `bindParam()` like that :

```
foreach($aQueryParams as $key=>&$value){
   $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);
}
```